# How do I get the position of a static body in Jbox2D?

Tags: jbox2d

I'm trying to get the position of a static body in JBox2D, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used JBox2D, but I think this is accurate. I looked at the [source](https://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/dynamics/Body.java) for the project and learned a lot (and you can too). Primarily that [body contains a `Transform`](https://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/dynamics/Body.java#61), and that the [`Transform`](https://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/common/Transform.java) contains the [position](https://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/trunk/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/common/Transform.java#38).

Since all those variables are public, it's likely you'll be able to access the position from:

`myStaticBody.m_xf.p`

Comment: thanx alot ...but its still not giving me the body's current position

Comment: You're going to need to add more details to your question. What have you tried already, what about it isn't working? Are you getting a position, but it's not the correct one? Details needed.

Comment: Vec2 position = body.getPosition();
   System.out.println(position.x);i have tried that but i only get one position which is its original position not its current position